# How to change font size of data which is coming from json file in ng2-smart-table?

Tags: css, angular

I used

```
:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table {font-size:22px;}
```

but there is no change in font size.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other rule with a higher precedence (maybe applied to the cells)? If not, paste a screenshot of element inspector from chrome, showing the styles for the table

Answer (score 0):

Inspect on it in  dev tools and override the class which effect the  font-size in the style file